# Notifications don't get fired - Android

Tags: android, android-intent, time, notifications, alarm

I'm trying to make an an app that sends **multiple scheduled alarms**, shown through a notification **according to a specific time** (not time interval, but time) every day.

I already implemented the `AlarmReceiver.class` that fires the notifications at each intent, but the problem is that I don't get any notification. I tried to show a `Log` inside the `onReceiver()` method, but the message hasn't been shown, so the alarm hasn't been reached.

This is the `setAlarm()` function, that sets the hour and the time to the `Calendar` I instantiated:

```
public void setAlarm()
{
    SharedPreferences pref = this.getSharedPreferences("NOTIFICATION_CODE", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String mName = NameFld.getText().toString();
    String mFormat = FormatSpn.getSelectedItem().toString();

    Date date = new Date();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar current = Calendar.getInstance();

    current.setTime(date);
    calendar.setTime(date);

    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, picker_hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, picker_minute);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);


    if(current.before(calendar))
    {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    }

    medName = mName;
    medFormat = mFormat;

    int _reqCode = pref.getInt("reqCode", -1);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, _reqCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager aManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    aManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pIntent);

    editor = pref.edit();
    editor.putInt("reqCode", ++_reqCode);
    editor.commit();

}
```

To set the time, I implemented a `TimePickerDialog` and I stored hour and minute values to `picker_hour` and `picker_minute`.
Since I have to send multiple alarms, I use `SharedPreferences` to store the `reqCode` used then to identify the `PendingIntent` every time one is sent.

This is the `AlarmReceiver.class` that fire a notification for each intent received. Every notification is identified through the same `reqCode` of the `PendingIntent`:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    String[] data = AddMedicine.getData();

    SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences("NOTIFICATION_CODE", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int reqCode = pref.getInt("reqCode", -1);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setTicker("It's pill time!");
    builder.setContentTitle(data[0]);
    builder.setContentText(data[1]);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    Notification notification = builder.build();
    NotificationManager nManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nManager.notify(reqCode, notification);
    Log.i("NOTIFICATION", "FIRED!");
}}
```

P.s. The alarm is set every time the user creates it, in order to schedule them through the `reqCode`.

So, anyone knows how to send **multiple alarms** according by time? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you have your `AlarmReceiver` class registered in the manifest?

Comment: I've got `<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" android:enabled="true"/>`, I think it's right....

Comment: I think this line: `current.before(calendar)` should be the other way round - `calendar.before(current)`, because like that you will always add one day if the alarm time is scheduled for future.